# How to tell MessageQueue.SendMessageConnection how to "XMLize" the object to be sent?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, message-queue

I'm working in C# with a `System.Messaging.MessageQueue.SendMessageConnection` for sending an object, containing some parameters, something like:

```
_sendQueue.Send(myObject, ...);
```

My `myObject` is an object, containing some attributes, like `Field1`.

I'm checking how my messages get sent, using:

- Computer Management
- Services and Applications
- Message Queuing
- Private Queues
- open the right queue, and in the "queue messages", right-click and check "Properties", "Body".

There I see tags like:

```
<Field1>content_Field1</Field1>
```

Instead of this, I would like to see something like:

```
<F1>content_Field1</F1>
```

Is there an easy mapping between the attributes in my object and the XML tags I would like to be used?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See: [Control XML serialization using attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes) - You can control the element naming with an attribute on the class property.

Comment: @Fildor: I checked the URL and did a first test and it looks great. Please write it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually quite easy to do. Check out [Control XML serialization using attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes) :

> By default, an XML element name is determined by the class or member name. In a simple class named Book, a field named ISBN will produce an XML element tag , as shown in the following example.

```
public class Book
{
    public string ISBN;
}
// When an instance of the Book class is serialized, it might
// produce this XML:
// <ISBN>1234567890</ISBN>.
```

> **This default behavior can be changed if you want to give the element a new name.** The following code shows how an attribute enables this by setting the ElementName property of a XmlElementAttribute.

```
public class TaxRates {
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "TaxRate")]
    public decimal ReturnTaxRate;
}
```

- Microsoft article as of 2017-03-30, various authors (emphasis by me)

The whole article is about a ~6minutes read and I really recommend it.